# Code optimisation for foreach in C#

Tags: c#

Code:

```
string testquestions = "1,2,100,3,4,101,98,99";
string[] qidarray = testquestions.Split(',');

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string s in qidarray)
{
    sb.Append(String.Format(@"({0}),",s));
}

string output= sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.ToString().Length - 1);
```

Desired output =

```
(1),(2),(100),(3),(4),(101),(98),(99)
```

The code works. I want to know is this the best way for achieving the result. Is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

Is there a way not to use a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Use String.Join()

Comment: This should be more appropriate for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would do the trick. The code is first splitting the string and using `linq`, formatting to desired output.

```
var strToPrint = string.Join(",", testquestions.Split(',')
                       .Select(s => string.Format(@"({0})", s)));
```

**Console Output**

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", testquestions.Split(',')
                        .Select(s => string.Format(@"({0})", s))));
```

You can check the live fiddle here - https://dotnetfiddle.net/4zBqMf

**Edit :**

As suggested by @paparazzo, you can use string interpolation to write the syntax as

```
var strToPrint = string.Join(",", testquestions.Split(',').Select(s => $"({s})"));
```

Live fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/xppLH2

Comment: fantastic. it worked. just one line of code. This is what I was looking for,

Comment: $"({s})"  is maybe cleaner.

Comment: @paparazzo - Agreed. Added in my answer.

Comment: @user1672994 you should use the real name: `"string interpolation"` rather than "string format short notation"

Comment: @maccettura - Done.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other ways using Replace.

```
string testquestions = "1,2,100,3,4,101,98,99";

string result = new StringBuilder("(" + testquestions + ")").Replace(",", "),(").ToString();

string result1 = "(" + testquestions.Replace(",", "),(") + ")";

string result2 = "(" + new Regex(",").Replace(testquestions, "),(") + ")";
```

Comment: perfect and simple